# Seleccionar palabras con condiciones

Tags: c++, array, r, select, rstudio

tengo la siguiente situación: de un conjunto de palabras, necesito seleccionar las que tengan una letra específica en una posición específica: por ejemplo las palabras que en el posición 5 tengan una letra e.

No tengo mucho código al respecto porque no he encontrado alguna función que se parezca a lo que necesito. **Estoy trabajando en RStudio**.

Quedo atento a sus comentarios.

Muchas gracias.

Saludos!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función `substr` obtiene el elemento en base a la posición que indiques.

por ejemplo si quieres el elemento en la posición 4 de la palabra "condición"

```
substr("condición", 4, 4)
```

devolverá la letra "d"

Ahora bien, si lo que quieres es retornar las palabras que cumplan la condición de que tengan una letra especifica en una posición especifica te dejo este ejemplo:

```
palabras = c("casa","ventana","puerta","ceramica")

letra = substr(palabras,2,2)

palabras[letra == "e"]
```

En este ejemplo estamos encontrando las palabras que tienen la letra "e" en la segunda posición

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Bastian. Tu respuesta está buenísima y me ayudó un montón.

Comment: Recuerda no resolver la tarea/proyecto sin que el usuario muestre algún esfuerzo por encontrar la solución. A la pregunta le hacía falta un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Saludos